# Prolog Accumulators. Are they really a "different" concept?

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion, accumulator

I am learning Prolog under my Artificial Intelligence Lab, from the source [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online).

In the 5th Chapter we come to learn about **Accumulators**. And as an example, these two code snippets are given. 
**To Find the Length of a List**

*without accumulators*:

```
len([],0).
len([_|T],N) :- len(T,X), N is X+1.
```

*with accumulators*:

```
accLen([_|T],A,L) :- Anew is A+1, accLen(T,Anew,L).
accLen([],A,A).
```

**I am unable to understand, how the two snippets are conceptually different? What exactly an accumulator is doing different? And what are the benefits?**

Accumulators sound like *intermediate variables*. (Correct me if I am wrong.) And I had already used them in my programs up till now, so is it really that big a concept?

Comment: As others have indicated in various ways, use of the accumulator gives you a solution which uses *tail recursion* which has optimization benefits. See, for example, the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096656/should-i-avoid-tail-recursion-in-prolog-and-in-general.

Comment: @false As I was quoting a literature, I let it be. Personally, I too would write facts before rules...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

accumulators *are* intermediate variables, and *are* an important (read *basic*) topic in Prolog because allow reversing the information flow of some fundamental algorithm, with important consequences for the *efficiency* of the program.

Take reversing a list as example

```
nrev([],[]).
nrev([H|T], R) :- nrev(T, S), append(S, [H], R).

rev(L, R) :- rev(L, [], R).
rev([], R, R).
rev([H|T], C, R) :- rev(T, [H|C], R).
```

nrev/2 (naive reverse) it's O(N^2), where N is list length, while rev/2 it's O(N).

Answer (score 13):

When you give something a **name**, it suddenly becomes more real than it used to be. Discussing something can now be done by simply using the name of the concept. Without getting any more philosophical, no, there is nothing *special* about accumulators, but they are useful.

In practice, going through a list without an accumulator:

```
foo([]).
foo([H|T]) :-
    foo(T).
```

The head of the list is left behind, and cannot be accessed by the recursive call. At each level of recursion you only see what is left of the list.

Using an accumulator:

```
bar([], _Acc).
bar([H|T], Acc) :-
    bar(T, [H|Acc]).
```

At every recursive step, you have the remaining list *and* all the elements you have gone through. In your `len/3` example, you only keep the count, not the actual elements, as this is all you need.

Some predicates (like `len/3`) can be made tail-recursive with accumulators: you don't need to wait for the end of your input (exhaust all elements of the list) to do the actual work, instead doing it incrementally as you get the input. Prolog doesn't have to leave values on the stack and can do tail-call optimization for you.

Search algorithms that need to know the "path so far" (or any algorithm that needs to have a state) use a more general form of the same technique, by providing an "intermediate result" to the recursive call. A run-length encoder, for example, could be defined as:

```
rle([], []).
rle([First|Rest],Encoded):- 
    rle_1(Rest, First, 1, Encoded).               

rle_1([], Last, N, [Last-N]).
rle_1([H|T], Prev, N, Encoded) :-
    (   dif(H, Prev) 
    ->  Encoded = [Prev-N|Rest],
        rle_1(T, H, 1, Rest)
    ;   succ(N, N1),
        rle_1(T, H, N1, Encoded)
    ).
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but I think this one is much better.

Comment: another great answer by user [@boris](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350352/849891).

Answer (score 13):

***TL;DR***: yes, they are.

Imagine you are to go from a city **A** on the left to a city **B** on the right, and you want to know the distance between the two in advance. How are you to achieve this?

A [*mathematician*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) in such a position employs [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613542/849891) known as [*structural recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_as_structural_transformations). He says to himself, what if I'll send my own copy one step closer *towards* the city **B**, and ask *it* of *its* distance to the city? I will then add 1 to its result, ***after*** receiving it from my copy, since I have sent it *one* step *closer* towards the city, and will know my answer without having moved an inch! Of course if I am already at the city gates, I won't send any copies of me anywhere since I'll know that the distance is 0 - without having moved an inch!

And how do I know that my *copy-of-me* will succeed? Simply because he will follow the same exact rules, while starting from a point *closer* to our destination. Whatever value my answer will be, *his* will be one less, and only a finite number of copies of us will be called into action - because the distance between the cities is finite. So the total operation is certain to complete in a finite amount of time and I *will* get my answer. Because getting your answer after an infinite time has passed, is not getting it at all - ever.

And now, having found out his answer in advance, our cautious magician mathematician is ready to embark on his safe (now!) journey.

But that of course wasn't magic at all - it's all being a dirty trick! He didn't find out the answer in advance out of thin air - he has sent out the whole *stack* of others to find it for him. The grueling work had to be done after all, he just pretended not to be aware of it. The distance *was* traveled. Moreover, the distance *back* had to be traveled too, for each copy to tell their result to their master, the result being actually created on the way ***back*** from the destination. All this before our fake magician had ever started walking himself. How's *that* for a team effort. For *him* it could seem like a sweet deal. But overall...

---

So that's how the [magician mathematician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) thinks. But his [*dual*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinduction) the brave traveler just [goes on a journey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism), and counts his steps along the way, adding 1 to *the current steps counter* on each step, ***before*** the rest of his actual journey. There's no pretense anymore. The journey may be finite, or it may be infinite - he has no way of knowing upfront. But at each point along his route, and hence when ⁄ if he arrives at the city **B** gates too, he will know his distance traveled so far. And he certainly won't have to go back all the way to the beginning of the road to tell himself the result.

And that's the difference between the structural recursion of the first, and *[tail recursion with accumulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) ⁄ [tail recursion modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) ⁄ [corecursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion)* employed by the second. The knowledge of the first is built on the way back *from* the goal; of the second - on the way ***forth*** from the starting point, *towards* the goal. The *journey* is the destination.

see also:

- [Technical Report TR19: Unwinding Structured Recursions into Iterations. 
   Daniel P. Friedman and David S. Wise (Dec 1974)](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19).

---

What are the practical implications of all this, you ask? Why, imagine our friend the *magician* mathematician needs to boil some eggs. He has a pot; a faucet; a hot plate; and some eggs. What is he to do?

Well, it's easy - he'll just put eggs into the pot, add some water from the faucet into it  and will put it on the hot plate.

And what if he's already given a pot with eggs and water in it? Why, it's even easier to him - he'll just take the eggs out, pour out the water, and will end up with the problem he already knows how to solve! Pure *magic*, isn't it!

Before we laugh at the poor chap, [we mustn't forget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) [the tale of the centipede](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centipede%27s_Dilemma). Sometimes ignorance *is* bliss. But when the required knowledge is simple and "one-dimensional" like *the distance* here, it'd be a crime to pretend to have no memory at all.