# Prolog recursion simple explanation

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have the following recursion rules which returns the sum of a number, but I don't know how does it return the sum:

```
sum(1,1).
sum(A,Result) :-
    A > 0,
    Ax is A - 1,
    sum(Ax,Bx),
    Result is A + Bx.
```

now when you execute the following command in Prolog:

```
sum(3,X).
```

the answer will be 5, but as I look into the rules, I can't see how does these rules return values and sum the. How is the value of Bx is calculated ?

Comment: see if [this general answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19951540/849891) helps.

Comment: in C this would be `sum(a){ if (a>0) {a + sum(a-1);} }`. Prolog makes the evaluation order much clearer, more explicit, less "mysterious".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum(3,X).` actually gives a result of `X = 6`. This predicate (`sum(N, X)`) computes the sum of integers from `1` to `N` giving `X`:

```
X = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N.
```

So it is the sum of the integers from 1 to N.

`sum(1,1)` says the sum of `1` by itself is just `1`. This is true. :)

The second clause should compute the sum for `A` > 1, but it's actually not totally properly written. It says `A > 0` which is ignoring the fact that the first clause already takes care of the case for `1`. I would have written it with `A > 1`. It will work as is, but be a little less efficient.

```
sum(A,Result) :-
    A > 0,
    Ax is A - 1, 
    sum(Ax, Bx),       % Recursively find the sum of integers 1 to A-1
                       % Instantiate Bx with that sum
    Result is A + Bx.  % Result is A plus sum (in Bx) from 1 to A-1
```

This clause recursively says that the sum of integers from `1` to `A` is `Result`. That `Result` is the sum of `A` and the sum of integers from `1` to `A-1` (which is the value `Ax` is unified to). The `Bx` is the intermediate sum of integers `1` through `Ax` (`A-1`). When it computes the `sum(Ax, Bx)`, the value of `Ax` is 1 less than `A`. It will continue calling this second clause recursively until the first parameter goes down to `1`, at which point the first clause will provide the value for the sum, and the recursion will unravel from there, summing 1, 2, 3, ...

**EDIT: More Details on the Recursion**

Let's look at `sum(3,X)` as an example.

`sum(3,X)` doesn't match `sum(1,1).` so that clause is skipped and Prolog looks at `sum(A, Result)`. Prolog matches this by instantiating `A` as `3` and `Result` as `X` and steps through the statements making up the clause:

```
% SEQUENCE 1
% sum(A, Result) query issued with A = 3

3 > 1,         % true
Ax is 3 - 1,   % Ax is instantiated as the value 2
sum(2, Bx),    % recursive call to `sum`, `Ax` has the value of 2
Result is 3 + Bx.  % this statement is awaiting the result of `sum` above
```

At this point, Prolog suspends computing `Result is A + Bx` in order to make the recursive call. For the recursive call, Prolog can't match `sum(Ax, Bx)` to `sum(1,1)` because `Ax` is instantiated as `2`. So it goes on to the next clause, `sum(A, Result)` and can match if it instantiates `A` as `2` and `Result` as `Bx` (remember, this is a new call to this clause, so these values for `A` and `Result` are a different copy than the ones we "suspended" above). Now Prolog goes through `sum(A, Result)` statements again, this time with the new values:

```
% SEQUENCE 2
% sum(A, Result) query issued with A = 2

2 > 0,         % true
Ax is 2 - 1,   % Ax is instantiated to the value 1
sum(1, Bx),    % recursive call to `sum`, `Ax` has the value of 1
Result is 2 + Bx.  % this statement is awaiting the result of `sum` above
```

Now Prolog has `sum(1, Bx)` (`Ax` is instantiated with `1`). This will match `sum(1,1)` and instantiate `Bx` with `1` in the last query to `sum` above in SEQUENCE 2. That means Prolog will complete the sequence:

```
Result is 2 + 1.   % `A` is 2 and `Bx` is 1, so `Result` is 3
```

Now that this result is complete, the recursive query to `sum` in the prior execution in SEQUENCE 1 will complete in a similar fashion. In this case, it is instantiated `Bx` with `3`:

```
Result is 3 + 3.  % `A` is 3 and `Bx` is 3 (from the SEQUENCE 2 query)
                  % so `Result` is 6
```

And finally, the original query, `sum(3, X)` completes, where `X` is instantiated with the result of `6` and you get:

```
X = 6.
```

This isn't a perfect explanation of how the recursion works, and there are some texts around with graphical representations that help. But I hope this provides some insight into how it operates.

Comment: i still don't see how Bx is evaluated, do you mean that each time sum(Ax,Bx) is executed it stores the value of Ax into Bx, but then sum(Ax,Bx) is suppose to be only true for one fact which is sum(1,1). The way is see it is that because sum(1,1) is true all other sum(Ax,Bx) are true. is that right or am i going side track here ?

Comment: @user733659 Every time `sum(A, Result)` is called, `Ax` and `Bx` get new values instantiated. `Ax` is set to `A-1`, then `Bx` is determined by recursive call to `sum(Ax, Bx)`. The definition of `sum(Ax, Bx)` is *`Bx` is the sum of integers from 1 to `Ax`*. This computation occurs recursively until it hits bottom at 1 (from `sum(1,1)`) then the values for `Bx` in each recursive call are instantiated at each level of recursion, added to `A`, and instantiate the `Result`.

Comment: @user733659 I updated my answer with more details about the recursion.