# Confused by "Init/Base" in foldr/foldl (Racket)

Tags: scheme, racket, abstraction, fold, higher-order-functions

I am close to understanding `foldr` and `foldl` but not quite there yet.

I understand that `foldr` is basically the stack implementation of performing some function on a list from "right to left".

So for `foldr`:

```
(define (fn-for-lon lon)
    (cond [(empty? lon) 0]
          [else
             (+ (first lon)
                (fn-for-lon (rest lon))]))
```

Is basically the equivalent of:

```
(foldr + 0 lon)
```

And I understand that `foldl` is basically the tail recursive, accumulator version that goes from "left to right".

So for `foldl`:

```
(define (fn-for-lon lon0)
    (local [(define (fn-for-lon lon acc)
                (cond [(empty? lon) acc]
                      [else
                          (fn-for-lon (rest lon) (+ acc (first lon)))]
   (fn-for-lon lon0)))
```

Is basically the equivalent of:

```
(foldl + 0 lon)
```

But what happens once you introduce two variables? I've tried to read on the topic but I just can't grasp it because no one talks about what is happening behind the scenes.

I'm really confused to whether or not the second argument is "base" or "init" or if it just depends on whether or not one or two variables are taken in the function. In the foldl example I gave it would seem to be the init acc value (which I suppose ends up being the base case), but in the foldr it would be the base case. Is it just because I only use an operator for the proc?

```
(foldr (lambda (a b) (cons (add1 a) b)) empty (list 1 2 3 4))
```

Something like the above I really just lose all understanding. I understand what to do, but not really what is happening in the background. This causes me to lose my track in more complex problems.

Is this the exact same thing and `b` is just the `empty`? Does `b` temporarily take on the `(rest lon)`?

```
(define (fn-for-lon lon)
  (cond [(empty? lon) empty]
        [else
         (cons (add1 (first lon))
               (fn-for-lon (rest lon)))]))
```

Comment: see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944969/prolog-accumulators-are-they-really-a-different-concept/19951540#19951540) helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the actual `foldl` from Racket:

```
 (define foldl
    (case-lambda
      [(f init l)
       (check-fold 'foldl f init l null)
       (let loop ([init init] [l l])
         (if (null? l) init (loop (f (car l) init) (cdr l))))]
      [(f init l . ls)
       (check-fold 'foldl f init l ls)
       (let loop ([init init] [ls (cons l ls)])
         (if (pair? (car ls)) ; `check-fold' ensures all lists have equal length
             (loop (apply f (mapadd car ls init)) (map cdr ls))
             init))]))
```

We see two cases: the first case `(f init l)` is there for efficiency. If only one list `l` is used, then we get a fast version of `foldl`.

The second case `(f init l . ls)` is the one you are after. Before we examine it, we need to look at the helper function `mapadd` first.

A call `(mapadd f l last)` will apply `f` to all elements of a list `l` and cons the result onto `last.

Example:

```
> (mapadd sqr '(1 2 3 4) 42)
'(1 4 9 16 42)
```

The definition of `mapadd`:

```
  (define (mapadd f l last)
    (let loop ([l l])
      (if (null? l)
        (list last)
        (cons (f (car l)) (loop (cdr l))))))
```

Back to the `(f init l . ls)` case of `foldl`.

Removing the error check it boils down to

```
       (let loop ([init init] 
                  [ls (cons l ls)])
         (if (pair? (car ls))
             (loop (apply f (mapadd car ls init)) 
                   (map cdr ls))
             init))]))
```

The initial value `init` is bound to a variable (also called) `init` which is used to accumulate the result. The variable `ls` is when the loop starts bound to a list of all lists `foldl` is called with. Note that these lists all have the same length. The loop continues until all the lists in `ls` are empty. The test `(pair? (car ls))` checks whether the first list is empty, but remember that the lists have the same length.

Now `init` is replaced with `(apply f (mapadd car ls init))`. This call first takes the first element of each list and conses on onto the current value of `init`. Then `f` is applied.

Consider this example: `(foldl + 0 '(1 2) '(10 11))` which evaluates to 24.
Here

```
 f    = +
 init = 0
 ls   = ((1 2) (10 11))
```

And

```
 > (mapadd car '((1 2) (10 11)) 0)
 '(1 10 0)
```

so

```
 > (apply + (mapadd car '((1 2) (10 11)) 0))
 11
```

In the next round we will see

```
 f    = +
 init = 11
 ls   = ((2) (11))
```

And `(apply + (mapadd car ls init)` will evaluate to 24.

An alternative way to explain the example `(foldl + 0 '(1 2) '(10 11))`.

```
(define init 0)
(for ([x (in-list '( 1  2))]              ; x and y loop in parallel
      [y (in-list '(10 11))])
  (set! init (apply + (list x y init))))  ; accumulate result in init
init
```

The complication in the implementation of `foldl` is that one doesn't know how many lists are used.

UPDATE

When foldl is used in practise it is best to think of `foldl` in terms of its specification and not of its implementation.

Here is how `foldl` is specified when called with two lists.

The call:

```
  (foldl f x0
     (cons a0 (cons a1 (cons a2 '())))
     (cons b0 (cons b1 (cons b2 '()))))
```

evaluates to the same as

```
(f a2 b2
   (f a1 b1
     (f a0 b0 
        x0)))
```

does.

As a check we can try it out:

```
>   (foldl (λ args (cons 'f args)) 'x0
       (cons 'a0 (cons 'a1 (cons 'a2 '())))
       (cons 'b0 (cons 'b1 (cons 'b2 '()))))
'(f a2 b2 (f a1 b1 (f a0 b0 x0)))
```

Note that `(λ args (cons 'f args))` is the function that just prepends a symbol `f` to its list of arguments.

Comment: OK, so I think basically it comes down to me trying to fit the definitions into the explanations of foldr/foldl that my teacher gave when in reality they were just simplified versions meant to show that one is tail reclusive, and one is not. The base is not the base case, it is the base init value that is to be accumulated on top of.

Comment: "The base is not the base case, it is the base init value that is to be accumulated on top of." Spot on.

Comment: @AdamThompson I have added a comment on how to think of `foldl` in terms of its specification. Try and make a similar rewrite rule for `foldr`.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `foldl` and `foldr` is always `init`. Your provided function must always take 2 arguments if you're passing in a single list, and the second argument to that function is the accumulated value (`init` initially, then the return value of the previous call to your function).

(In your earlier examples of using `+`, you can think of it as being the same as `(lambda (a b) (+ a b))`. In this case, `a` is the list element, and `b` is the accumulated value.)

When you're calling `foldl` or `foldr` with N lists, then your provided function must take N+1 arguments; the first N arguments correspond to the next element from each list, and the last argument is the accumulated value (`init` initially, then the return value of the previous call to your function).

---

Would it help your understanding if I provided (my own) implementations of `foldl` and `foldr`? Here they are:

```
(define foldl
  (case-lambda
    ;; one list
    [(func init lst)
     (let loop ([result init]
                [rest lst])
       (if (null? rest)
           result
           (loop (func (car rest) result) (cdr rest))))]

    ;; multiple lists
    [(func init list1 . list2+)
     (let loop ([result init]
                [rests (cons list1 list2+)])
       (if (ormap null? rests)
           result
           (loop (apply func (append (map car rests) (list result)))
                 (map cdr rests))))]))

(define foldr
  (case-lambda
    ;; one list
    [(func init lst)
     (let recur ([rest lst])
       (if (null? rest)
           init
           (func (car rest) (recur (cdr rest)))))]

    ;; multiple lists
    [(func init list1 . list2+)
     (let recur ([rests (cons list1 list2+)])
       (if (ormap null? rests)
           init
           (apply func (append (map car rests)
                               (list (recur (map cdr rests)))))))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Folds are really there to help us, not to confuse us. They capture a certain recursion pattern for consistent reuse.  Folds are defined abstractly, and are easiest understood abstractly as well. The only reason to get into the specifics of your language's implementation of folds is to make sure that the implementation is valid.

Whenever we have a specific pattern of recursion (writing in an equational pseudocode),

```
foo(xs) =
  matches xs with
     Empty -> zero
     Cons(head,tail) -> comb(head, 
                                foo(tail))
```

where we combine the head of list with the *recursive result of invocation of `foo` on the list's tail*, we've got ourselves a (right) fold, and calling **`foo(xs)`** is the same as calling **`foldr(comb, zero, xs)`**. *How* exactly is this implemented in our language of choice is beside the point.

As you can see, the combining function (operator, or whatever) *must* accept the "current element" of  list as its first argument, and the recursive result, as its *last*. *Only when* there are no more elements in the list, `zero` value is used in place of the recursive result, *initiating* the chain of `comb` calculations performed on the way back from the recursion's base case, `Empty`.

So when reading the folding definitions, we always treat the combining function's first argument as the ***"current element"***, mentally, and the last as ***"recursive result*** of processing the **rest** of the list".

Why this wording about the "current" element? Because, imagining our list is **`[a,b,c,...,n]`**, calling **`foldr(comb, z, [a,b,c,...,n])`** is, according to the above pattern, the same as calling

```
comb(a, 
      foldr(comb, z, [b,c,d,...,n]))
==
comb(a,
   comb(b,
      comb(c, 
         ......, comb(n, z)......)))
```

This *is*, in a sense, the definition of right fold on lists, a.k.a. the list *catamorphism*.

Racket adds to this the ability to fold over several lists in parallel, at the same time. Naturally, the arrangment of the arguments to the combining function remains the same – all arguments but the last one correspond to the current elements, each from each argument list; and the last argument is the ***recursive result*** to combine them with.

A similar but different pattern is

```
bar(xs) =
  matches xs with
     Empty -> zero
     Cons(head,tail) -> comb(head, 
                                tail, 
                                   bar(tail))
```

which is known as *paramorphism* (cf. [`maplist` vs. `mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) in Common Lisp).

Since both capture recursion, `zero` corresponds to the base case of the inductive data definition we are recursing on:

```
List of 'a =  Empty 
           or Cons('a, List of 'a)
```

*Starting* from the base case, we get a dual pattern, of building up a value *before* the recursive call,  a.o.t. after it as above, with

```
baz(zero, xs) =
  matches xs with
     Empty -> zero
     Cons(head,tail) -> baz( comb(head, zero),
                                tail)
```

which you will recognize as the left fold (and `zero` is not a base case value anymore, but a value being built on the go, – or accumulated, – and *finally* returned when `Empty` case is hit).

So it's just about the difference between the ***`(1+(2+(3+...(n+0)...)))`*** with the right fold, and the ***`(...(((0+1)+2)+3)...+n)`***, with the left <sub>(showing it with the order of arguments flipped, for the conveniece of representation)</sub>. One's result will be the same as the other's, when `(+)` is an associative operation. Which, for numbers, it is.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951540/849891).