# Prolog Recursion and Variables

Tags: sorting, recursion, prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I have this insertion sort to sort a list in descending order in Prolog and it works:

```
insert(X,[],[X]).
insert(X, [Y|Tail], [X,Y|Tail]):- X > Y, !.
insert(X, [Y|Tail], [Y|NTail]):- insert(X, Tail, NTail).
ins_sort([], []).   
ins_sort([X|Tail], Sorted):- ins_sort(Tail, STail), insert(X, STail, Sorted).
```

I am running it on SWISH and trying to understand how it functions with the following trace:

```
 Call:ins_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], _12162)
 Call:ins_sort([2, 3, 4, 5], _12358)
 Call:ins_sort([3, 4, 5], _12358)
 Call:ins_sort([4, 5], _12358)
 Call:ins_sort([5], _12358)
 Call:ins_sort([], _12358)
 Exit:ins_sort([], [])
 Call:insert(5, [], _12360)
 Exit:insert(5, [], [5])
 Exit:ins_sort([5], [5])
 Call:insert(4, [5], _12366)
 Call:4>5
 Fail:4>5
 Redo:insert(4, [5], _12370)
 Call:insert(4, [], _12282)
 Exit:insert(4, [], [4])
 Exit:insert(4, [5], [5, 4])
 Exit:ins_sort([4, 5], [5, 4])
 Call:insert(3, [5, 4], _12378)
 Call:3>5
 Fail:3>5
 Redo:insert(3, [5, 4], _12382)
 Call:insert(3, [4], _12294)
 Call:3>4
 Fail:3>4
 Redo:insert(3, [4], _12294)
 Call:insert(3, [], _12300)
 Exit:insert(3, [], [3])
 Exit:insert(3, [4], [4, 3])
 Exit:insert(3, [5, 4], [5, 4, 3])
 Exit:ins_sort([3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3])
 Call:insert(2, [5, 4, 3], _12396)
 Call:2>5
 Fail:2>5
 Redo:insert(2, [5, 4, 3], _12400)
 Call:insert(2, [4, 3], _12312)
 Call:2>4
 Fail:2>4
 Redo:insert(2, [4, 3], _12312)
 Call:insert(2, [3], _12318)
 Call:2>3
 Fail:2>3
 Redo:insert(2, [3], _12318)
 Call:insert(2, [], _12324)
 Exit:insert(2, [], [2])
 Exit:insert(2, [3], [3, 2])
 Exit:insert(2, [4, 3], [4, 3, 2])
 Exit:insert(2, [5, 4, 3], [5, 4, 3, 2])
 Exit:ins_sort([2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2])
 Call:insert(1, [5, 4, 3, 2], _12162)
 Call:1>5
 Fail:1>5
 Redo:insert(1, [5, 4, 3, 2], _12162)
 Call:insert(1, [4, 3, 2], _12336)
 Call:1>4
 Fail:1>4
 Redo:insert(1, [4, 3, 2], _12336)
 Call:insert(1, [3, 2], _12342)
 Call:1>3
 Fail:1>3
 Redo:insert(1, [3, 2], _12342)
 Call:insert(1, [2], _12348)
 Call:1>2
 Fail:1>2
 Redo:insert(1, [2], _12348)
 Call:insert(1, [], _12354)
 Exit:insert(1, [], [1])
 Exit:insert(1, [2], [2, 1])
 Exit:insert(1, [3, 2], [3, 2, 1])
 Exit:insert(1, [4, 3, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1])
 Exit:insert(1, [5, 4, 3, 2], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
 Exit:ins_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

I get lost once I get beyond the first "Exit". I understand all of the recursive calls until we get to an empty list, which stops the recursive calls because of the other fact and begins going back, but why after the first exit on line 7 does the undefined STail become an empty list [] in the insert call?

Has the exit of ins_sort([], []) set STail to an empty set [] and does this mean that the last argument of a fact is a return value or something?

Comment: In SWI prolog it's best to use graphical tracer.  You will get more info and also you can see how it works. Simply type in "guitracer". and then "tracer."

Comment: EDIT: I figured out how to use guitracer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is you are having some difficulty understanding what happens with variables during recursion. Let's take a simplified case:

```
count([], 0).
count([X|Xs], N) :- count(Xs, N0), succ(N0, N).
```

What happens when I call `count([a,b], N)` is this:

```
count([a, b], N)
 +-> count([b], N)
```

The first thing we have to do upon entering `count([a,b], N)` is a recursive call to `count/2`. When Prolog re-enters count, we suddenly have a new set of bindings for `X` and `Xs`. In the outer call, `X=a` and `Xs=[b]`, but in the inner call, `X=b` and `Xs=[]`. There will then be a third inner call, which begins with the `Xs` value `[]`. This corresponds to the first three lines of this trace:

```
Call: (8) count([a, b], _8636) ? creep
Call: (9) count([b], _8866) ? creep
Call: (10) count([], _8866) ? creep
```

What the tracer is telling you here is "I am trying to enter this predicate with these values and variables." Note that the variable actually changed for N between the first and second calls.

Now, you'll notice that the `[]` cannot match the second clause, only the first. The first doesn't have a body but it does establish a binding. So the next line of the trace will reflect that:

```
Exit: (10) count([], 0) ? creep
```

See the numbers on the side? That's telling you the depth of the call stack. It's convenient to use numbers for traces instead of showing the nesting visually because eventually our call stacks are going to get pretty deep!

Now that we have a value for the variable, it's going to move on to the next expression in the clause we're in:

```
Call: (10) succ(0, _8866) ? creep
Exit: (10) succ(0, 1) ? creep
```

Nesting level went up one but was immediately resolved; this is par for the course with built-ins like `succ/2`. Now let's look at the rest of the trace:

```
Exit: (9) count([b], 1) ? creep
Call: (9) succ(1, _8636) ? creep
Exit: (9) succ(1, 2) ? creep
Exit: (8) count([a, b], 2) ? creep
```

So now that we had a binding for the recursive call, we can enter the next step in the parent call, and so on, until the whole call is resolved and we get 2.

Let's see it again, this time with nesting instead of numbers:

```
[trace]  ?- count([a,b],N).
  Call: (8) count([a, b], _8636) ? creep
    Call: (9) count([b], _8866) ? creep
      Call: (10) count([], _8866) ? creep
      Exit: (10) count([], 0) ? creep
      Call: (10) succ(0, _8866) ? creep
      Exit: (10) succ(0, 1) ? creep
    Exit: (9) count([b], 1) ? creep
    Call: (9) succ(1, _8636) ? creep
    Exit: (9) succ(1, 2) ? creep
  Exit: (8) count([a, b], 2) ? creep
N = 2.
```

This should make what's going on in your own trace a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Traces are much too hard. Re-writing is usually much easier, especially with the deterministic predicates like you have here. Long variable names are also too distracting. Instead of reading and remembering, it just might be easier simply seeing:

```erlang
insert(X, [],    [X]).                                                                %1
insert(X, [Y|T], [X,Y|T] ):- X > Y, !.            % X was indeed greater than Y:      %2
                                                  %   accept the solution and stop;   %3
insert(X, [Y|T], [  Y|NT]):- insert(X, T, NT).    %   otherwise, insert into tail.    %4
                                                                                      %5
ins_sort( [],   []).              % rule {1}                                          %6
ins_sort( [X|T], S):-             % rule {2}                                          %7
   ins_sort( T,     ST),                                                              %8
   insert( X,       ST,                                                               %9
                 S).                                                                 %10
```

Let's try it with a shorter list,

```erlang
  ins_sort([1, 2, 3], S) ?                                                S.         %11
=           \                                                            /           %12
  {2:      [X1|T1]=[1,2,3] }                                            /            %13
      ins_sort(T1, ST1),                               insert(X1, ST1, S).           %14 
=               \                                                 /                  %15
      {2:      [X2|T2]=T1=[2,3] }                                /                   %16
          ins_sort(T2, ST2),                    insert(X2, ST2, ST1).                %17
=                   \                                      /                         %18
          {2:      [X3|T3]=T2=[3] }                       /                          %19
              ins_sort(T3, ST3),         insert(X3, ST3, ST2).                       %20
=                       \                          /                                 %21
              {1:      T3=[]                     ST3=[] }.                           %22
```

and we go by the V-shaped trace from the top left corner down to the middle, winding up the recursion until we reach the base case, and then up and to the right while unwinding the recursion and building the result on our way back from the base case, [as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951540/849891). Thus we proceed to establish, from the bottom up,

```erlang
  ST3 = [].                                                                          %22
  insert( {X3=3}, {ST3=[]}, ST2 ):- ST2 = [3].                                       %20
  insert( {X2=2}, {ST2=[3]}, ST1 ):- ST1 = [3,2].                                    %17
  insert( {X1=1}, {ST1=[3,2]}, S ):- S = [3,2,1].                                    %14
```

And that's that.

Comment: Nice ASCII-Art you've got going on there, s(X)   8-)

Comment: @tas having fun, :) thanks. vision is a massively parallel subsystem of human cognition, so, why not use it more.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog works with unification and pattern matching.You are removing the Head and calling the predicate again with tail which keeps removing Head and tries to find matches after each call and at some later time you have an empty list so prolog search your file for a match and at this point it finds a match `ins_sort([], []).`
 
At 6th call you have `Call:ins_sort([], _12358)` where `_12358` is a variable and this variable will get the value from `ns_sort([], []).` which is a fact. It simply means that if you have one empty list in ns_sort and one variable then set that variable also equals to the empty list, variable gets instantiated with anything if you have all other "terms" matching.

Prolog can be easily understood by learning Backtracking and backtracking is an algorithm so prolog self is an algorithm.

Comment: "At 6th call you have Call:ins_sort([], _12358) where _12358 is a variable and this variable will get the value from ns_sort([], [])." - I understand that's what's happening, but my question is WHY does it happen? Why does ins_sort([], []) set STail to [] and why does that value remain when backtracking through the recursive calls?

Comment: "STail"  has a capital "S" in front of it which means it is a variable and also un-instantiated!.  Why does `in_sort([],[])` set Stail to []. It's because you have a matching predicate name `in_sort and in_sort` both have same first "term(make difference between term and variable)" which is empty list `[] = []` but Stail is refering to some memory location which is free so it says ok if the rest all things match since Stail is an "uninstantiated variable" so i instantiate that memory location with second term and i will get one succesive branch. Note: you can't change the value of variable.

Comment: it remains same because Stail is referening to same memory location and one more thing in prolog you can't change variable value. I mean if  `N is 1` and you then say `N is N+1`

Comment: So, does that mean that it doesn't set the other variable, Tail, to [] because it's already instantiated Maybe a better thing to ask is why doesn't Tail also get set to [] then? When it it starts going backwards, it's still 5, not []?

Comment: No it does not set Tail = [] but Since in each call you remove head and after sometime your list has no head and Tail = [] at that time it finds  match, Once it finds match it has succes and starts getting back values from stack, in this case it starts getting H's back from the stack and the only purpose of this process was to initializ the memory location of Stail.

Comment: `Call:insert(5, [], _12360)` This is result of this call `insert(X, STail, Sorted).` not of backtraking.

Comment: *You are removing the Head and calling the **function** again....* In Prolog, they're *predicates* not *functions*. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: There are no redos in the chain before the first exit. The OP is confused by the structure of the stack trace and recursion here, whether or not they are also confused about backtracking.

Comment: @DanielLyons it's difficult to explain and i'm no expert but i tried and main thing he/she does not understand is unification.

Comment: I disagree about your diagnosis.